# show/hide ul li based on id

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to show certain `li` based on id. So when I click on class c1. It will show me just list info about *africa*. Now it shows every `li` from demo-agents. This one is "menu". It is a map. After clicking on continent it rolls me down and points on certain `li id`. So when I click on class c1. It points me to `li id="africa"` and shows me the text.

But now it shows every `li id`. I would like to hide all `li id africa-s.america`. And when I click on class c1 it will show below `li id africa`.

```
<div id="map-continents">
  <ul class="continents">
    <li class="c1"><a href="#africa">Africa</a></li>
    <li class="c2"><a href="#asia">Asia</a></li>
    <li class="c3"><a href="#australia">Australia</a></li>
    <li class="c4"><a href="#europe">Europe</a></li>
    <li class="c5"><a href="#north-america">North America</a></li>
    <li class="c6"><a href="#south-america">South America</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and then info

```
<div id="demo-agents" class="demo-agents-list wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li id="africa"><h3>Africa</h3><p>Some info about Africa</p>  </li>
    <li id="asia"><h3>Asia</h3><p>Some info about Asia</p>  </li>
    <li id="australia"><h3>Australia</h3><p>Some info about Australia</p>  </li>
    <li id="europe"><h3>Europe</h3><p>Some info about Europe</p>  </li>
    <li id="north-america"><h3>North America</h3><p>Some info about North America</p>  </li>
    <li id="south-america"><h3>South America</h3><p>Some info about South America</p>  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.c1').each(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
       $('.demo-agents-list wrapper').hide();
       $('.' + $(this).attr('id')).fadeIn(600);
     }
     });
```

I hide div in CSS. But Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/jamesking/8rc2kepw/2/

```
$(function() {
  $("#demo-agents li").hide();
   $(".continents li a").on('click', function(e) {
        var liToShow = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#demo-agents li").hide();
        $(liToShow).show();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: When I use this on jsfiddle it is working, but on my website not. I don't get it. But many thanks

Comment: Actually tested it and created a fiddle. It should work on your site now

Comment: still not.. the thing is I am not clicking on text but on map https://postimg.org/image/deemyxfvz/

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
       $("#demo-agents li").hide(); 
       $(".continents li").click(function(){ 
         var crntlink = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
         $("#demo-agents li").hide(); $(crntlink).show(); 
       }); 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#demo-agents li").hide();
  $(".continents li").click(function(){
    var crntlink = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $("#demo-agents li").hide();
    $(crntlink).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

css

```
/*Hide the li with the maps, not the container div. the container div
  must be visible, or else the children will always be invisible.*/
#demo-agents li { display:none }
```

jquery

```
$("#map-continents li")
  .each(function() { //Show the one who is selected by default
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $('#demo-agents li').hide();
      $($(this).find("a").attr('href')).fadeIn(600);
    }
  })
  .on("click", function() { //bind click event
    $("#map-continents .selected").removeClass("selected") //Remove "selected" class
    $(this).addClass("selected")        
    $('#demo-agents li').hide(); //Hide the maps again
    $($(this).addClass("selected").find("a").attr('href')).fadeIn(600); //Show the right map
  })
```

Comment: not working :( . I edit `<ul style="display: none;">` and use  `$(".c1").click(function() {
  $("ul").show();})` and it is showing all ...how can I choose which to show..something like ("ul, asia").show

Comment: you are right, i made an error. I think you should study my example here. https://jsfiddle.net/4to96doc/

Comment: Thank you..it is working in jsfiddle, but not on website. I need to find where is the problem